# Indice Fulltext não está filtrando no where do select

Tags: php, mysql, full-text

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada `boletos`, e criei um índice FULLTEXT para a coluna `categoria`, que é a coluna onde irá mais na busca do *where*.

Fiz tudo correto, só que na hora de buscar, ele não está filtrando o resultado no *where*. Ele simplesmente traz todos os resultados da tabela e o que eu busquei ele coloca no topo da tabela, e gostaria que ele trouxesse apenas o resultado que busquei.

Não sei se é meu *select* que está correto, mas vou postar aqui meu código.

boletos:

```
id int auto increment
boleto mediumblob//arquivo pdf,jpeg
nomeBoleto varchar,//nome do arquivo
tipoBoleto varchar,//tipo do arquivo(.pdf ou .jpeg)
categoria varchar,//só tem 2: Pagamento Mensal e Pagamento Anual
primary key (post_id),
FULLTEXT (categoria)//indice pra pesquisar por categoria
```

Meu PHP está assim:

```php
<?php
include "conexão.php";

 //aqui puxa minha categoria do campo
$categoria = $_POST['comboB'];

//e meu select
$stmt = $db->prepare("select id,nomeBoleto,categoria from boletos WHERE MATCH (categoria) AGAINST ('$categoria' in boolean mode)");

$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
  if($row > 0){ 

<tr>                
  <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['nomeBoleto']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['categoria']?></td>                 
</tr>

  }
?>
```

Ele simplesmente traz todos os registros colocando o que eu busquei no topo da tabela, sendo que é pra trazer apenas o que eu coloquei para trazer.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Coloque , se possível , os dados.

Comment: Como assim os dados?

Comment: Os dados inseridos e que tentou buscar, pode ter impacto.

Comment: Os dados que eu busco entra na coluna categoria, e que está no where do meu select...nessa coluna categoria só tem duas opções que é: Pagamento Mensal e Pagamento Anual, não sei se influencia pq as palavras são iguais..já li algo sobre, mas não consigo resolver :(

Comment: @Motta editei a pergunta e coloquei na frente das colunas os tipos de dados que são inseridos, se puder me ajudar..to quebrando a cabeça pra resolver isso..

Comment: O problema pode estar nos dados , que "categoria" consta na tabela e que categoria pesquisou ? Não conheço "fulltext" mas pode ser isto

Comment: Nesta coluna categoria só tem duas opções que é: Pagamento Mensal e Pagamento Anual, fulltext é indices de tabela mysql, eu nunca trabalhei com isso, primeira vez que to mechendo tb.. :(

Comment: Creio que o que vai demandar no caso é o "pagamento" , talvez fosse o caso de se usar uma busca exata, não ?

Comment: é que a busca está vindo de uma variavel que pega o valor de um select para o post, pq o usuario que seleciona o tipo que ele quer pesquisar... : $categoria = $_POST['comboB'];..mas o conflito é or as palavras serem iguias..vou pesquisar melhor aqui...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Como funciona a pesquisa com índices Fulltext**

Para cada registro, o MySQL atribui um valor de relevância, que representa a similaridade da string de pesquisa com a linha em questão. Um valor de relevância 0 (zero) significa nenhuma semelhança, fazendo com que o registro não seja exibido.

Esse cálculo de relevância é feito através de um algoritmo projetado para pesquisa em grandes massas de texto, *tornando a busca inadequada para pequenas tabelas*. Entre as variáveis que são levadas em consideração nesse cálculo, o MySQL considera o número de palavras encontradas em cada campo do índice, o número de palavras encontradas por linha, o número de ocorrências da mesma palavra em todas as linhas, entre outros. Quanto mais rara for a palavra, maior será seu peso no cálculo da relevância.

**Sobre o modificador IN BOOLEAN MODE**

O MySQL pode executar procuras booleanas de texto completo usando o IN BOOLEAN MODE. Com esse modificador, certos caracteres têm um significado especial no início ou no final das palavras da string de pesquisa. **Onde, os operadores + e - indicam que uma palavra deve estar presente ou ausente, respectivamente, para que uma correspondência ocorra.**

Levando esses fatos em conta, parece que sua consulta:

```
SELECT id, nomeBoleto, categoria FROM boletos WHERE MATCH (categoria) AGAINST ('$categoria' in boolean mode)
```

Deveria ser: (observe o sinal de mais +)

```
SELECT id, nomeBoleto, categoria FROM boletos WHERE MATCH (categoria) AGAINST ('+$categoria' in boolean mode)
```

> Referências:
>
> [Índices FULLTEXT no MySQL](https://www.devmedia.com.br/indices-fulltext-no-mysql/7631)
>
> [Pesquisas de texto completo booleano](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)
>
> [MySQL Match Against In Boolean Mode returns nothing on middle
>   word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004674/mysql-match-against-in-boolean-mode-returns-nothing-on-middle-word)